# Javascript ES6: How to retrieve calling subclass from a static method defined in superclass

Tags: javascript, es6-class

New to JavaScript.

Seeking some guidance on how to access the calling class name from a ***static method*** defined in the superclass using ES6 classes.  I've spent an hour searching, but have not been able to come up with a solution.

A code snippet may help clarify what I am seeking

```
class SuperClass {
    get callingInstanceType() { return this.constructor.name }
    static get callingClassType() { return '....help here ...' }
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass { }

let sc = new SubClass()

console.log(sc.callingInstanceType)     // correctly prints 'SubClass'
console.log(SubClass.callingClassType)  // hoping to print 'SubClass'
```

As illustrated above, I can easily get the subclass name from a instance.  Not quite sure how to access from a static method.

Ideas for the implementation of `static get callingClassType()` welcomed.

Comment: You'll be hard pressed to find a way to do that in any language. Because static method means no this, so there is no notion of "the calling instance".

Comment: Try `return SuperClass.constructor.name;`

Comment: @Derek, that returns `Function`, not `SubClass`.  Is there any way to inspect the call chain and pull out from there?

Comment: @Kevin I do get there is no calling instance.  I was wondering if there was some way to inspect the chain.

Comment: It seems kinda redundant to have such a method in the first place. The user already knows the name of the class because they use it, whether directly or as a variable. You could just do `SuperClass.prototype.constructor.name` and get what you need

Comment: @Derek.  I do have logic to my madness as to why I want to achieve this.  It has it's purpose - but whether it is possible is what I'm not so sure about.

Comment: @Kevin Actually it's pretty easy in PHP: [`get_called_class()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php). And as Felix's answer shows below it's doable in JS too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`callingClassType` is a function (well, a getter in this case, same thing). The value of `this` inside a function depends on how it is called. If you call a function with `foo.bar()`, then `this` inside `bar` will refer to `foo`.

Thus if you "call" the function with `SubClass.callingClassType`, `this` will refer to `SubClass`. `SubClass` is itself a (constructor) function thus you can get its name via the `name` property.

So your method definition should be

```
static get callingClassType() { return this.name; }
```

```js
class SuperClass {
  get callingInstanceType() {
    return this.constructor.name
  }
  static get callingClassType() {
    return this.name
  }
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass {}

let sc = new SubClass()

console.log(sc.callingInstanceType)
console.log(SubClass.callingClassType)
```

Have a look [at the MDN documentation to learn more about `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you.  Simple when you know how.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SuperClass.prototype.constructor.name`:

```js
class SuperClass {
    get callingInstanceType() { return this.constructor.name }
    static get callingClassType() { return SuperClass.prototype.constructor.name; }
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass {}
class SubClass2 extends SuperClass {
     static get callingClassType() { return SubClass2.prototype.constructor.name; }
}

console.log(SuperClass.callingClassType); // 'SuperClass'
console.log(SubClass.callingClassType); // 'SuperClass'
console.log(SubClass2.callingClassType); // 'SubClass2'
```

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static#Examples:

```
class Triple {
  static triple(n) {
    if (n === undefined) {
      n = 1;
    }
    return n * 3;
  }
}

class BiggerTriple extends Triple {
  static triple(n) {
    return super.triple(n) * super.triple(n);
  }
}

console.log(Triple.triple());        // 3
console.log(Triple.triple(6));       // 18

var tp = new Triple();

console.log(BiggerTriple.triple(3));
// 81 (not affected by parent's instantiation)

console.log(tp.triple());
// 'tp.triple is not a function'.
```

Comment: Thanks @Derek.  But I want `SubClass.callingClassType` to return `SubClass`, not `SuperClass`

Comment: You'd have to re-define the function in `SubClass` to get that value because the function is not on the prototype of `SubClass` unless you add it.

Comment: I added an example `SubClass2` that redefines the method.